# Upload to S3 without exposing your accessKeyId

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a web app that uses **firebase** for authentication and database and **Angular4** for the front end. I am uploading images to **AWS S3** via my web app and it works fine.

## Problem:

I am currently using my **accessKeyId** and **secretAccessKey** inside my angular4 code to upload the files directly to AWS S3 (using the AWS SDK for javascript). When angular is compiled, it is still just javascript that is still used on the front end by the client browser. I dont like this and it poses a security risk for me.

How can I upload images to S3 from Angular4 directly without exposing my keys ?

Comment: write credential on a yml file, load it via backend. dont upload via frontend, do it on backend. upload image and post it to backend, from there u do the upload.

Comment: Sounds good thx ! I was thinking of using aws lambda... Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a small back-end service/API that can generate [AWS S3 pre-signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). Your Angular application can then use that pre-signed URL to upload an image to S3. The back-end service will be the only thing that needs your AWS access permissions.

AWS Lambda + API Gateway would be perfect for this sort of back-end service.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yeah I am busy doing this right now. Think it will be the best solution thanks !